# Test in Rails console model associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Hello I do have this two models and I would like to check that my model associations are working the way it should trough rails console.

I am not able to do the association work. The relationship is the following:
One Event has one rule and one rule belongs to one event. It could not be a rule without an event and it could not be a event without a rule.

Any idea how to test this with rails console?

MODEL 1:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    has_one :rule
    has_many :grand_prixes
    belongs_to :eventable, polymorphic: :true
end
```

MODEL 2

```
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :events
end
```

Rules' Schema:

```
  create_table "rules", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean  "abs"
    t.boolean  "tc"
    t.boolean  "allow_auto_clutch"
    t.boolean  "allow_sc"
    t.boolean  "allow_throttle_blip"
    t.boolean  "dynamic_track"
    t.integer  "damage_mult"
    t.integer  "fuel_rate"
    t.integer  "tyre_wear_rate"
    t.integer  "quali_percentage"
    t.integer  "min_valid_laps"
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
  end

  add_index "rules", ["event_id"], name: "index_rules_on_event_id"
```

Events' Schema:

```
create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "event_type"
    t.string   "name",           null: false
    t.datetime "starting_date"
    t.datetime "ending_date"
    t.integer  "eventable_id"
    t.string   "eventable_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end

  add_index "events", ["eventable_type", "eventable_id"], name: "index_events_on_eventable_type_and_eventable_id"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Event it is polymorphic because other relationship is implemented.

Comment: _Sidenote_: there should be foreign key `'event_id'` on `rules`. Adding this  mandatory consistency checker to the schema might shed a light on what’s going wrong. Also, `['event_id']` on `rules` should be a unique index (due to “one rule belongs to one event”.)

Comment: I wrote the following inside the migration:

`add_index "rules", ["event_id"], name: "index_rules_on_event_id", unique: true`

Now I do have it on my schema but I am not able to make the link through console. 
Thanks for your fast reply :)

Comment: Did you delete the precisions about your console commands ? Can you add them back ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `belongs_to :events` should be singular to follow the rails convention :

```
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

The conventional name of a relation is always singular for `belongs_to` and `has_one`, and always plural for `has_many`.

Related documentation : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference

EDIT : There much left to say

You wrote :

```
ev = Event.create(:name "test1").save
rule = Rule.create.save
```

- `create` is already a `new` followed by a `save`. No need to save afterwards.
- the syntax `key: value` is something very common in ruby, and should be well understood : you're actually writing a hash, equivalent to `{:key => value}`, but the syntax allows you to write `key: value` ONLY IF your key is a Symbol.
- the columns `eventable_type` and `eventable_id` should be in the table `rules`, who is hosting the polymorphic relation with eventable things. Event should not have these columns, and event_id should not exist at all in rules.

Here's an example of what you can write in your console to create an Event and a Rule :

```
ev = Event.create(name: "test1")
rule = Rule.create(abs: true, event: ev)
```

Comment: It was a typo :P thanks for your reply, still not understanding how to properly test it in console.

Comment: I wrote my new code below could check it please :? thanks @caillou

Answer (score 0):

Change your code:

```
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :event
end
```

With `belongs_to` you should use singular like `event` not `events`.

In console you can check association like:

```
Event.first.rule if Event.first.present?
```

For more details you should go through http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html documentation.

Comment: Could you explain further the previous test cases using console? I mean I do have an empty database, so if I want to test the association I should create (and save) the Object first right? But how is it the way to link both objects (Event & Rule) through console. 
If I run "Event.first.rule if Event.first.present?" in console everytime I am getting a "nil" response. 
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Current code:

```
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    has_one :rule
    has_many :grand_prixes
    belongs_to :eventable, polymorphic: :true
end
```

SCHEMA:

```
  create_table "rules", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean  "abs"
    t.boolean  "tc"
    t.boolean  "allow_auto_clutch"
    t.boolean  "allow_sc"
    t.boolean  "allow_throttle_blip"
    t.boolean  "dynamic_track"
    t.integer  "damage_mult"
    t.integer  "fuel_rate"
    t.integer  "tyre_wear_rate"
    t.integer  "quali_percentage"
    t.integer  "min_valid_laps"
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
  end

  add_index "rules", ["event_id"], name: "index_rules_on_event_id", unique: true





  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "event_type"
    t.string   "name",           null: false
    t.datetime "starting_date"
    t.datetime "ending_date"
    t.integer  "eventable_id"
    t.string   "eventable_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end

  add_index "events", ["eventable_type", "eventable_id"], name: "index_events_on_eventable_type_and_eventable_id"
```

Tested on console:

```
ev = Event.create(:name "test1").save
rule = Rule.create.save
```

No idea how to link it both through console.